# perl script on apache server

Tags: apache, perl

getting 404 not found when hitting http://myServerIp/cgi-bin/echo.pl

this is my 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
         <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                         AllowOverride None
                         Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI +Includes +IncludesNOEXEC -Indexes
                         AddHandler cgi-script .pl
                         Order allow,deny
                         allow from all
         </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

My echo.pl is placed inside "/var/lib/cgi-bin"
Please guide me , where I m doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your `Directory` and `ScriptAlias` Points to `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`:

`<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">`

not to `"/var/lib/cgi-bin` where your script is located.

Comment: Sry, Placed inside "/usr/lib/cgi-bin" but still same 404 error

Comment: @AditiGoyal have th pl file execution permisssion? Please take a look into the Apache error log file if there are some entries regarding the file

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
> ```
>
> My echo.pl is placed inside "/var/lib/cgi-bin"

`/var/lib/cgi-bin` and `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` are different directories.

Comment: Sry, Placed inside "/usr/lib/cgi-bin" but still same 404 error